# Good verb for "to make more concise"?

Tags: synonyms

There seem to be many good adjectives to descibe a sentence which effectively gets the point across without wasting words: "concise", "succinct", "terse", "pithy".

But what is a good verb to make the following sentence more concise:

> Please make this sentence more concise.

Comment: cut the sentence short..

Comment: In a lighthearted context I'd love to use *succinctify*. It's great to say aloud :) But sadly isn't a real word.

Comment: *Shorten*. That being said, no matter how short a verb you use, the sentence will still be asking for being made *shorter still*. So ideally, you should scrap it altogether.

Comment: I think the duplicate path should be reversed. Despite being asked later, this question has higher quality answers, more clear phrasing, 17x more views, and is more highly rated than the marked duplicate.

Comment: I disagree with two of the comments above — _concise_ does _not_ have the same meaning as _short_.

Comment: Depending on the context, and on the shade of meaning you intend to convey, I would suggest any of the following: _refine_, _distill_, _hone_, _focus_, _streamline_, or _abbreviate_.

Answer (score 13):

You can use "[condense](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condense)"

You could also use "summarise" if it suits your context.

Comment: unlike concise,succinct,terse and pithy, **condense** does not denote accuracy. So I believe condense can not be used as a replacement for the above mentioned verbs.

Comment: IIRC, "condense" is a term that was used in news publication/editing circles. Can't get more accurate than that.

Comment: Can you you share links of those publications? And what was the context in which "condense" was used? "Concise information" denotes  both accuracy and briefness of given information but if you condense a piece of information, you just make it short and concentrated. The outcome may or may not be accurate.

Comment: @SandeepD "The outcome may or may not be accurate." Don't know where you got that notion. It's wrong/

Comment: Not sure where @SandeepD got it from, but when I look _condense_ up in a dictionary, it says 'to compress into fewer words; abridge'—nothing about preserving accuracy or detail.

Answer (score 4):

If someone was asked to just *shorten* a sentence, it would likely to be done to still preserve the most vital content. One could also *streamline* it, *edit it down*, *trim* it, or *concentrate* it.

Comment: 'it would likely to be done to still preserve the most vital content'—I really wish that matched my experience! I'm upvoting this for _streamline_, though.

Answer (score 3):

Please [precis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Precis?s=t) this sentence (not included in the list of options given in the suggestion included in the comments above).

Additionally...

You could use distill - see 5 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Distill?s=t).

Comment: Why would someone down-vote it? The sentence makes perfect sense.

Comment: Agreed - if you're going to down-vote, at least indicate why.

Comment: Seems to be an uncommenting lazy *ç%&/ of a downvoter making the rounds today

Comment: Precis is not the same thing. To make something more concise means to present the same information but using fewer words. A precis is a high-level summary containing much less information.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In the context, which related to a single sentence, I think this achieves the intended effect. I've added 'distill' as a suggestion, though, which is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **[focus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus)** is often used, often in imperative sentences, to get a speaker or writer

> to concentrate attention or effort

This is especially found where the narrative has drifted into verbosity or inconsequentials.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "focus this sentence". The natural way, "make this sentence more focused", is exactly the same length as "make this sentence more concise".

Comment: @DavidRicherby The term appears most often in response to a wandering tale in which the listener says *Focus!*

Comment: I agree. So it's hard to use it to rewrite "Please make this sentence more concise" in a way that's more concise.

Answer (score -1):

Make this sentence more *proverbial*.

A proverb is pith perthonified (I mean personified).

Moreover, a sentence which is crafted to be more proverbial just might be more memorable, which is one of the marks of both a proverb and a strong sentence.

An example of "before and after":

> "Due to the fact that I saw it with my own eyes, I can bear witness to the fact that it really did happen because I saw it happen."

And

> "Because I saw it happen, I know it happened."