# Single English Word for "to make more concise"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm writing a review of Richard Lanham's [*Revising Prose*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0205309453).

> *Revising Prose* provides detailed examples and tutorials that will help you clarify, simplify, and make your writing more concise.

What word can I use to replace "make your writing more concise"?

Comment: "Condense"....?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this site. Please try English SE.

Comment: concisificationing (no, just kidding)

Comment: @WeckarE. I've updated my question to point readers to English Language & Usage. How do I close this interchange in the same way as https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/24031/a-single-english-word-for-not-chaos?

Comment: @RyanBrookePayne Once five people vote to migrate this question to English.SE, it'll be automatically moved there, and I assume the users there will swiftly close it as a duplicate of one of the questions you mentioned. My vote makes three, so we just need two more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good verb for "to make more concise"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152584/good-verb-for-to-make-more-concise)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, feel free to mark this as a duplicate. I mistakenly posted it first in Writing Stack Exchange and then it was migrated here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["To make terse" (an insufficiently prolix title)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134627/to-make-terse-an-insufficiently-prolix-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try "*Revising Prose* provides examples and tutorials that will clarify your writing." I also like the verbs tune up and sharpen.

There is a bit more tightening that could be done: "Using examples and tutorials, *Revising Prose* will clarify your writing." Or you could break it up something like this: "*Revising Prose* will clarify your writing. Using examples and prose, . . ."

Comment: I used your second suggestion: https://medium.com/docsfordevs/technical-writing-resources-for-software-developers-ada066af1bbc

Comment: You're using the word *tightening*, but you're not suggesting it. What's wrong with *clarify, simplify, and tighten your writing*?

Comment: @PeterShor That's a great suggestion. I've updated my blog post: https://medium.com/docsfordevs/technical-writing-resources-for-software-developers-ada066af1bbc.

Comment: Revising might well include expounding for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You could try “... and shorten your writing.”

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I find that when the end of one of my sentences is too long, the whole sentence should be tightened. I like to think of my text as a tweet that must convey everything with no characters wasted.

Thus, in your case, I came up with:

> *Revising Prose* explores how to write clearer and concise writing.

I took out "simpler" as I felt that was implied.

Then I considered that "explores how to" has a single word replacement:

> *Revising Prose* demonstrates writing clearer, concise writing.

Which it should not take a genius to realise is a horrible sentence with needless repetition. Thus I went further:

> *Revising Prose* examines concise and clearer writing.

19 words reduced to 7.

If this was me, I would now move on to talking about the tutorials.

Comment: You don't *"write writing"*. You write prose.

Comment: @Peter Shor Isn't that a quote from _Popeye_?

Answer (score 0):

One can (sometimes) resort to a neologism that relies on established meaning:

Revising Prose provides detailed examples and tutorials that will help you clarify, simplify, and 'compact-ify' your writing.

OR 
Revising Prose provides detailed examples and tutorials that will help you clarify, simplify and [consolidate] your writing, into its most effective essence.

OR 
Revising Prose provides detailed examples and tutorials that will help you clarify, simplify, and [concentrate] your writing into its most effective essence.